# What's the meaning of "hit somebody like a bucket of cold water"?

Tags: idiom-meaning

What's the meaning of "hit somebody like a bucket of cold water"? I couldn't find this idiom (?) in my dictionaries; I just found "cold water" means "disapproval". But I don't think it would have the same meaning in this idiom.

Examples:

- The bad news hit me like a bucket of cold water.
- My presence will hit them like a bucket of cold water.

Comment: How do you feel when a bucket of cold water is poured upon you?

Comment: I would feel shocked or it might make me more alert.

Comment: This idiom probably comes from last year's Ice Bucket Challenge.

Comment: Yes, that's how you would feel.

Comment: @Joe Dark Or perhaps not {[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=like+a+splash+of+cold%2Clike+a+bucket+of+cold&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clike%20a%20splash%20of%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clike%20a%20bucket%20of%20cold%3B%2Cc0)}. Assuming we know when (if) it achieved the status of an idiom.

Comment: So does it imply "to be shockening to somebody "? ,@Rathony

Comment: I think the below answers explain it.

Comment: "Hit me like a bucket of cold water" has no direct relationship to "throw cold water on" -- two distinctly different meanings.

Answer (score 2):

**"It was a bucket of cold water on my feelings"** can be considered a figure of speech. Your sentence **"it hit me like a bucket of cold water"**, however, stands literally for what it is: a comparison, you felt as if someone had thrown a bucket of cold water on you. Using "like" changed a figure of speech into a comparison.

Comment: I don't agree. Similes **are** figures of speech. 'It hit me like a bucket ['s prior contents] of cold water' obviously doesn't imply 'exactly like' that water. That would require a bucketful of equally cold, dense, wetting, viscous, colourless, odourless ... fluid hitting the person. There are one or more points of similarity in a simile (and an awful lot of differences). 'He's like a tiger.'

Comment: Yes, I think it is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is similar to the saying   "***[throw cold water on](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throw+cold+water+on)***" and means that the news surprised and discouraged you, as something you probably didn't expect:

> - To express misgivings about or disapproval of; discourage.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: Yes, cold water is cold and surprising. :)

Comment: Incorrect.  Even winning the Nobel Prize could hit you "like a bucket of cold water" if you were in a literal or figurative stupor when the water hit.  The expression has nothing to do with "cold water" as a metaphor for disapproval or discouragement.